# SDL2 Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 (M1 Mac)

Tags: sdl-2, apple-m1

I have issue with SDL2 on mac now, I'm compiling using `makefile` with `g++ -arch arm64 -std=c++14 -Wall -g`, and link all `.o` and `libSDL2*.a` with a seperate rule.
The SDL2 is installed with homebrew with version 2.0.22, I confirmed the .a files are for arm64 with `lipo --info`.
Compile is fine, but generates A LOT `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64` when linking, here is some example:

```
"_AudioObjectAddPropertyListener", referenced from:
    _COREAUDIO_Init in libSDL2.a(SDL_coreaudio.o)
    _audioqueue_thread in libSDL2.a(SDL_coreaudio.o)
"_AudioObjectGetPropertyData", referenced from:
    _prepare_device in libSDL2.a(SDL_coreaudio.o)
    _assign_device_to_audioqueue in libSDL2.a(SDL_coreaudio.o)
    _device_unplugged in libSDL2.a(SDL_coreaudio.o)
    _build_device_list in libSDL2.a(SDL_coreaudio.o)
"_AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize", referenced from:
    _build_device_list in libSDL2.a(SDL_coreaudio.o)
"_AudioObjectRemovePropertyListener", referenced from:
    _COREAUDIO_CloseDevice in libSDL2.a(SDL_coreaudio.o)
    _COREAUDIO_Deinitialize in libSDL2.a(SDL_coreaudio.o)
    _audioqueue_thread in libSDL2.a(SDL_coreaudio.o)
...
"_objc_opt_isKindOfClass", referenced from:
    -[SDLWindow sendEvent:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoawindow.o)
    -[Cocoa_WindowListener windowWillMove:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoawindow.o)
    _Cocoa_CreateWindowFrom in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoawindow.o)
    -[SDLTranslatorResponder insertText:replacementRange:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoakeyboard.o)
    -[SDLTranslatorResponder setMarkedText:selectedRange:replacementRange:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoakeyboard.o)
"_objc_opt_respondsToSelector", referenced from:
    -[Cocoa_WindowListener handleTouches:withEvent:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoawindow.o)
    _Cocoa_CreateWindow in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoawindow.o)
    _Cocoa_CreateWindowFrom in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoawindow.o)
    -[SDLMessageBoxPresenter showAlert:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoamessagebox.o)
    _IOS_GameControllerGetAppleSFSymbolsNameForButton in libSDL2.a(SDL_mfijoystick.o)
    _IOS_GameControllerGetAppleSFSymbolsNameForAxis in libSDL2.a(SDL_mfijoystick.o)
    _IOS_AddJoystickDevice in libSDL2.a(SDL_mfijoystick.o)
    ...
"_objc_release", referenced from:
    _Cocoa_CreateWindow in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoawindow.o)
    _Cocoa_DestroyWindow in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoawindow.o)
    _Cocoa_SetWindowTitle in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoawindow.o)
    -[SDLMessageBoxPresenter showAlert:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoamessagebox.o)
    -[METAL_RenderData dealloc] in libSDL2.a(SDL_render_metal.o)
    -[METAL_TextureData dealloc] in libSDL2.a(SDL_render_metal.o)
    _METAL_CreateRenderer in libSDL2.a(SDL_render_metal.o)
    ...
"_objc_retain", referenced from:
    -[SDLMessageBoxPresenter initWithParentWindow:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoamessagebox.o)
    _Cocoa_InitMouse in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoamouse.o)
    _Cocoa_CreateSystemCursor in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoamouse.o)
    -[SDLTranslatorResponder setMarkedText:selectedRange:replacementRange:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoakeyboard.o)
"_objc_setProperty_nonatomic", referenced from:
    -[SDL_RumbleMotor setEngine:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_mfijoystick.o)
    -[SDL_RumbleMotor setPlayer:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_mfijoystick.o)
    -[SDL_RumbleContext setM_low_frequency_motor:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_mfijoystick.o)
    -[SDL_RumbleContext setM_high_frequency_motor:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_mfijoystick.o)
    -[SDL_RumbleContext setM_left_trigger_motor:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_mfijoystick.o)
    -[SDL_RumbleContext setM_right_trigger_motor:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_mfijoystick.o)
    -[METAL_RenderData setMtldevice:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_render_metal.o)
    ...
"_objc_sync_enter", referenced from:
    _ScheduleContextUpdates in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoawindow.o)
    -[SDLOpenGLContext setWindow:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoaopengl.o)
"_objc_sync_exit", referenced from:
    _ScheduleContextUpdates in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoawindow.o)
    -[SDLOpenGLContext setWindow:] in libSDL2.a(SDL_cocoaopengl.o)
```

Comment: Static libraries don't hold any dependency information; this is consistent across all major desktop OSes. If you link with dynamic library, it'll automatically pull its dependencies. If you chose to use static instead, you'll have to provide full dependencies list yourself. Take a look at https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/83f5bbdf25eafa38818a60d6a0cea90d90e25dc7/CMakeLists.txt#L2115, and add all required `-framework` options to your build. Or reconsider your use of a static library.